# MySQL Access in Php to a database created in C-Panel

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

Basically, i'm having trouble connecting to a mysql database using a php web page.
 I created the database in C-panel using the wizard
i'm connecting like this

```
$db_host = "localhost"; //your host Database address

$db_username = "xxxx"; //your account username

$db_pass = "xxxxx"; //your account password

$db_name = "xxxxx"; //your database name

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to     mysql");

@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");
```

But all my page seems to do is trigger the " could not connect to mysql" 
my page does have wordpress installed at the minute but I'm planning to get rid of it as I'm creating my site myself. I'm just baffled why it can't connect, because in Phpmyadmin ( a feature on C-panel) it says the database is in localhost.

Comment: Are you sure the user name and password are correct? Also you should output the error (`mysql_error()`) to see what's going wrong.

Comment: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'Localhost' (10061)"

Answer (score 0):

In C-panel you need to add database user and assign certain roles to it before you can connect to the database.

Comment: Are you sure MySQL service is running on that server? If you have username, password and server name correct than it must be something wrong with the server itself. You might need to check with server support. However, if you are running the database locally (on your own machine) than it could be some firewall; antivirus and similar issue.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure, I might have to contact customer support. At first I thought it might be because of wordpress, but unlikely.